# fastest way of writing to text file and csv file

Tags: c#, file-io

I have created a application which will be running on server and receiving packets from client. The application job is to receive packets, parse them and analyse it and generate results. I packet are in acceptable format then I write them to csv file or generate log file if they are not in correct format. My application is running fine but when I did profiling of performance of my application I found out most of the cpu cycles or time is spend on writing to csv file and to write to log file. If csv file becomes large then too much time or cycles are spent in writing to csv file.
Following is my code for writing to log file and csv file :-

```
TextWriter tsw = new StreamWriter(@filename, true);
                    tsw.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " ");
                    tsw.WriteLine("Message recieved from client(" + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint + ") : ");
                    tsw.WriteLine();
                    tsw.Close();

static private void csv_print(string pol, params string[] printall)
    {
        string filename = string.Format(pol + ".csv");
        TextWriter tsw = new StreamWriter(@filename, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < printall.Length; i++)
        {
            tsw.Write("\"" + printall[i] + "\",");
        }
        tsw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        tsw.Close();
    }
```

So are their any better and faster way of writing to log file and csv file(when data in csv file becomes large)?

Comment: I think your are doing it the right way. Using Streams is very efficient. And you mentioned that your application is running fine. So I wouldn#t change anything.

Comment: How about [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.file.appendalltext.aspx) with `string.Join(",", printall)`? - Oh, forgot about the surrounding quotation marks. Okay, so maybe use a `StringBuilder` here. So I don't know if that'll be faster.

Comment: My application is running fine but problem is that I parse every packet received from client and write it to csv file if they are in correct format and then send acknowledgement to client. This sending acknowledgement is fast after receiving the packet but when csv file becomes large this process of writing to csv file becomes slow and thus their is delay in sending acknowledgment to client.

Comment: Does it have to be one big CSV file, or would it be possible to split it up in certain intervalls (daily, hourly, etc.)? - or maybe a database would be a better option to store that information.

Comment: ok how should I do it if I want split it up hourly

Comment: Change `"fileName.csv"` to `"fileName" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHH") + ".csv"`. So every hour the filename will be different. But it depends on what you want to do with the CSVs and logs after they are written, if it is a good idea to split them.